# Gettng Access Token for a SSO login user

Tags: java, automated-tests, single-sign-on, rest-assured, rest

I wanted to get access token in order to access the API for our application. Importantly, I am able to get access token through postman. I have replicated the same in java Rest Assured code by going through online materials which says to get authorize code first then pass it in token url to get the access token, but I always end up in a response of type text/html for authorize step. Also, it shows the following error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sign in to your account</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://aadcdn.msauth.net" crossorigin>
<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="on">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msauth.net">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msftauth.net">

    <meta name="PageID" content="ConvergedError" />
    <meta name="SiteID" content="" />
    <meta name="ReqLC" content="1033" />
    <meta name="LocLC" content="en-US" />

        <meta name="referrer" content="origin" />


    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=" />
    </noscript>

    
    
<meta name="robots" content="none" />

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$Config={"strHeaderText":"Sign in","unsafe_strTopMessage":"Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.","strMainMessage":"We received a bad request.","strAdditionalMessage":"","strServiceExceptionMessage":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: \u0026#39;scope\u0026#39;.","strTraceId":"43b3c9f3-5d82-43e1-ae7e-fcb88fe24d00","iErrorCode":900144,"iHttpErrorCode":400,"iViewId":1,"urlCancel":"","strTimestamp":"2021-08-23T18:09:43Z","urlLearnMoreRiskyApp":"https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2133457","iMaxStackForKnockoutAsyncComponents":10000,"fShowButtons":true,"fEnabledFlaggedSigninFlow":true,"urlCdn":"https://aadcdn.msauth.net/shared/1.0/","urlFooterTOU":"https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/servicesagreement/","urlFooterPrivacy":"https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacystatement","iPawnIcon":0,"sPOST_Username":"","sFTName":"flowToken","dynamicTenantBranding":null,"staticTenantBranding":null,"fEnableLayoutTemplates":true,"oAppCobranding":{},"iBackgroundImage":2,"fApplicationInsightsEnabled":false,"iApplicationInsightsEnabledPercentage":0,"urlSetDebugMode":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/debugmode","fEnableCssAnimation":true,"fAllowGrayOutLightBox":true,"fIsRemoteNGCSupported":true,"fUseSameSite":true,"uiflavor":1001,"fOfflineAccountVisible":false,"scid":1013,"hpgact":1800,"hpgid":1117,"pgid":"ConvergedError","apiCanary":"AQABAAAAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7Wevr4vgU5dSyj56ii8l46ni2Rlv-gbTV2fIzqJIZnmVvo36GN53V3xSnHh5tMvCuWoooKdZMo9EdfVDONwnh2GgbIDGAN_B1AjGh8Hp1P5BuOwdAgdkHrcxUmzKCivfO5qKbuG8mEyfK7w0wOcdk33wnPqkZU-N_Kh6GBxCHFt_5VMVU4LGhfBi9z9FKR9khgg94FHH3ozYq6Io8vIR1sDHjgyAA","canary":"/5Mr0VLUDgJZmi+BudaCdz5N6AwqT1rk13F4BqW281Y=8:1","correlationId":"103f8f0c-3657-447d-ba14-b899e94fa7aa","sessionId":"43b3c9f3-5d82-43e1-ae7e-fcb88fe24d00","locale":{"mkt":"en-US","lcid":1033},"slMaxRetry":2,"slReportFailure":true,"strings":{"desktopsso":{"authenticatingmessage":"Trying to sign you in"}},"enums":{"ClientMetricsModes":{"None":0,"SubmitOnPost":1,"SubmitOnRedirect":2,"InstrumentPlt":4}},"urls":{"instr":{"pageload":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/instrumentation/reportpageload","dssostatus":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/instrumentation/dssostatus"}},"browser":{"ltr":1,"_Other":1,"Full":1,"RE_Other":1,"b":{"name":"Other","major":-1,"minor":-1},"os":{"name":"Unknown","version":""},"V":-1},"watson":{"url":"/common/handlers/watson","bundle":"https://aadcdn.msauth.net/ests/2.1/content/cdnbundles/watson.min_ybdb1ixzkv-fkor2mu6q6w2.js","sbundle":"https://aadcdn.msauth.net/ests/2.1/content/cdnbundles/watsonsupportwithjquery.3.5.min_dc940oomzau4rsu8qesnvg2.js","fbundle":"https://aadcdn.msauth.net/ests/2.1/content/cdnbundles/frameworksupport.min_oadrnc13magb009k4d20lg2.js","resetErrorPeriod":5,"maxCorsErrors":-1,"maxInjectErrors":5,"maxErrors":10,"maxTotalErrors":3,"expSrcs":["https://login.microsoftonline.com","https://aadcdn.msauth.net/","https://aadcdn.msftauth.net/",".login.microsoftonline.com"],"envErrorRedirect":true,"envErrorUrl":"/common/handlers/enverror"},"loader":{"cdnRoots":["https://aadcdn.msauth.net/","https://aadcdn.msftauth.net/"],"logByThrowing":true},"serverDetails":{"slc":"ProdSlices","dc":"SEASLR1","ri":"SI2XXXX","ver":{"v":[2,1,11935,14]},"rt":"2021-08-23T18:09:43","et":0},"clientEvents":{"enabled":true,"telemetryEnabled":true,"useOneDSEventApi":true,"flush":60000,"autoPost":true,"autoPostDelay":1000,"minEvents":1,"maxEvents":1,"pltDelay":500,"appInsightsConfig":{"instrumentationKey":"69adc3c768bd4dc08c19416121249fcc-66f1668a-797b-4249-95e3-6c6651768c28-7293","webAnalyticsConfiguration":{"autoCapture":{"jsError":true}}},"defaultEventName":"IDUX_ESTSClientTelemetryEvent_WebWatson","serviceID":3},"fApplyAsciiRegexOnInput":true,"fBreakBrandingSigninString":true,"fFixIncorrectApiCanaryUsage":true,"fTrimChromeBssoUrl":true,"inlineMode":5};
//]]></script>
```

My code to get Authorize token looks like this

```
        oAuthToken = given()
                .Header("authorization", "Basic " + <encoded username and password>)
                .contentType(ContentType.URLENC)
                .formParam("response_type", "code")
                .queryParam("client_id", "<xyz client id>")
                .queryParam("redirect_uri", "<the call back url>")
                .queryParam("scope", "user.read")
                .post("/oauth2/v2.0/authorize")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .extract()
                .response();
```

Can someone help me with this. I am trying this since two days and unable to get it done. What is the mistake I am doing? Why am I not getting a JSON response with authorization code for my authorize post method?

The setting in the postman that works for me looks like below:

[image: Postman Setting for Access Code]

Comment: The error message clearly indicates your request is missing "scope".  It doesn't appear that you're sending it in a way that the server can understand it. Exactly what your request should look like will likely be closely tied to your organization's oauth implementation, and not something we'll be able to help you with.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, I have provided the scope in the header. Tried with sending the scope in the body too. Nothing worked. :(

Comment: It's going to be something specific to your oauth implementation. Also in the code you're showing, you seem to be providing the scope in the query params, not the headers.

Comment: @BhuvaneshwariK could you provide setting in postman that works for you.

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 i have added the postman screenshot in the question. Please have a look

Comment: Could you show the rest-assured code that sent the scope as a body parameter?

Comment: @MarekŻylicz I am not getting this error in my code anymore, but still getting html response only.  I did send the body parameters as a string, with each parameter concatenated with a & symbol  and it worked without error, but still returning only a HTML page not authorization code